# Reuse cached chunks from html in pdf

Tags: r

I have an Rmarkdown file that runs a large number of simulations and takes about 10 hours to run. I have done so with html output and caching all the chunks. Now I need to do the same with pdf output, but if I simply knit to pdf Rmarkdown will rerun all the simulations. Is there any way to reuse the cached chunks already done for html output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this is too-little-too-late, but for other people with a similar problem, you can do:

```r
knitr::knit("some-markdown-file.Rmd")
```

To create a markdown file called "some-markdown-file.md" (or anything else you want, by specifying arguments to `knit()`. This is when your time-consuming code is actually evaluated.

You can then use this file to render html or pdf documents, by running:

```r
rmarkdown::render("some-markdown-file.md",
                  output_format = c("html_document", "pdf_document"))
```

##### This kind of works for Quarto docs

Note that (at the time of writing) this won't 'just work' for Quarto documents, because `knit()` reads the file extension to guess what to do. But if you specify the `output = "something.md"` in `knit()` it should all work (but will get you an rmarkdown-looking document as opposed to a quarto-looking one)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I can't reuse the results I already have, but I can run the Rmd just one more time and then create whatever output I want?

Comment: Thanks Captain Hat. As he says, didn't help me this time but good to know for the future.